# "Couldn't read dependencies" error with npm

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I wanted to start a Node app and created a ***package.json*** file with a tutorial. Here is the json file:

```
{
    "name": "Dashboard",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Client-A Dashboard",
    "dependencies": {
        "socket.io": "latest",
        "express": "latest",
        "jade": "latest"
    },
    "author": "tD"
}
```

I verified JSON file before trying to run it, but still I got an error message when I ran the `npm install` command:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\projects\Client-A\Live\package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\projects\Client-A\Live\
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\projects\Client-A\Live\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\Client-A\Live\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

and here is the ***npm-degub.log*** file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.2.14
3 info using node@v0.8.22
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose read json C:\projects\Client-A\Live\package.json
6 error install Couldn't read dependencies
7 error Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\projects\Client-A\Live\package.json'
8 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
8 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
8 error or email it to:
8 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
9 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
10 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
11 error cwd C:\projects\Client-A\Live\scoreboard
12 error node -v v0.8.22
13 error npm -v 1.2.14
14 error path C:\projects\Client-A\Live\package.json
15 error code ENOENT
16 error errno 34
17 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Comment: Can you confirm you are running `npm install` from the same directory as the package.json file?

Comment: Yes, I was in same directory

Comment: Open the CMD with run as administrator and try to install.

Comment: I received permission error when I tried without "run as admin". I got the error above with admin privileges.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to add this:

`"private": true,`

it worked for me.

**EDIT** (for people asking why):

The [Oficial documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html) states the following:

---

*If you set `"private": true` in your package.json, then npm will refuse to publish it.
This is a way to prevent accidental publication of private repositories. If you would like to ensure that a given package is only ever published to a specific registry (for example, an internal registry), then use the `publishConfig` hash described below to override the `registry` config param at publish-time.*

---

The error messages you are getting may be related to violating this "rule" in a way (mine was).

- Either you are marking a unpublished package (like your own app) as
  `"private": false`.
- Or you are neglecting to include any value at all.

Comment: glad it did, I hope it does help more people :)

Comment: Why does this fix it? I got a similar issue but this could not fix it. Is there something deeper here? (thank you for your answer though! - just trying to find what's going on with my build :) )

Comment: Ahh nevermind, realized I wasn't in the right directory when running it. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too. but why?

Comment: "private": true, :where should i add this ?

Answer (score 58):

I had an `"Invalid Name"`

I switched from `"name": "Some Name",...` to `"name": "Some-Name",...`

Guess `name` needs to be a sluggy string.

Comment: Is this documented any where?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. I never reported it either :/

Comment: Thanks mate.  That was my issue.  Darn slugs..  :)

Comment: This was it for me too.

Answer (score 26):

Recently, I've started to get an error:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: Invalid version: "1.0"
```

So, you may need to specify `version` of your package with 3 numbers, e.g. `1.0.0` instead of `1.0` if you get similar error.

Answer (score 13):

It's simple, you're just not in the right directory.

Go to the  `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` and you should be able to run this command properly.

Comment: That's one possible cause, but definitely not the only one.

Comment: For me this was the problem.

Answer (score 11):

**Try to update npm,It works for me**

```
[sudo] npm install -g npm
```

Comment: What does this do? This worked for me but I cannot use `npm install` on it's own.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same exception also, but it was previously running fine in another machine. Anyway above solution didn't worked for me. What i did to resolve it?

1. Copy dependencies list into clipboard.
2. enter "npm init" to create fresh new package.json
3. Paste the dependencies again back to package.json
4. run "npm install" again!

Done :) Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, weird, after manually creating the node_modules folder and the package.json file, it worked

Comment: Yeah i was struggling to run it then search over but couldn't make it work. Finally above method worked for me. Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the version. Yes, the line you put at the root, like :

```
{
    "name": "your-project",
    "version": "0.1"
    ...
}
```

Yes, npm doesn't like version like this, it prefers something like "`0.0.1`".

Don't ask me why, I'll tell you it's totally stupid (or "how to loose time easily")

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was the I named the file `packages.json` instead of `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I wasn't in the correct folder. I needed goto the folder I just cloned before I ran this command.

Comment: Lol, I just did the same thing and seeing your answer made me use my brain. Thank you. :)

Comment: Glad my mistake was not in vain :) and Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I had a space in my "name" within the packagae.json file.

"NPM Project" rather than "NPMProject"

Answer (score 0):

---

Problem with not reading the json is linked to permission issues with the file.

Using this command will do the trick:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like your issue, but for the sake of others, for me this was caused by an invalid version number in package.json (had to change 2.4 to 2.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

1)Nodejs installs in C:\ProgramFiles in some cases. Try installing in C: drive or another directory if you don't have admin rights.

2)Make sure you are not installing behind a company's proxy setting. This can sometimes affect installation.

3) Finally, make sure you run the npm command from this directory:
Path\nodejs\node_modules\npm
where Path is your own directory.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that problem just moving my project from E: to C:. I think it happened becouse nodejs and npm was installed in my C: and the project was in my E:

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after I cloned a git repository to a directory, renamed the directory, then tried to run `npm install`.  I'm not sure what the problem was, but something was bungled.  Deleting everything, re-cloning (this time with the correct directory name), and then running `npm install` resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Verify user account, you are working on. If any system user has no permissions for installation packages, npm particulary also is showing this message.

Answer (score -2):

I was following a doc on line and thought this error meant a problem with the dependencies in NPM. however after a third look. I realized that it was a typo. I did not add a comma after the first dependency in package.json that the tutorial asked me to edit.