# npm install not creating node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am just trying to run npm install . in a local directory, and keep getting these errors:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "."
npm ERR! node v4.4.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a     package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
```

All I'm doing is cd'ing into my directory and running npm install . I have a packages.json file in there, as well. Any idea why this isn't working???
EDIT: contents of packages.json file is below:

```
{
  "name": "speech-recognition",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "speech recognition app",
 "main": "application.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "node server.js"
 },
 "author": "Lisa Buch",
 "license": "ISC"
 }
```

Comment: you say you have `package.json` directory in there. Mind sharing its contents? It's supposed to be a file, not a directory so I'm curious what's in it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant file! I'll add the contents of it to my post now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please check your current directory. It should contain a package.json file with proper structure and dependencies.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

If you don't have a package.json file, means you are creating a project from scratch. In this case you can create package.json file using following command.

```
npm init
```

and install the packages with providing the package name with npm install command. e.g. if you want to install express package. use the following command

```
npm install express --save
```

Here --save option will update you package.json file with the package and its version.

Comment: I ran npm init and the package was created correctly. Now, when I run npm install, I get the following messages: npm WARN package.json speech-recognition@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json speech-recognition@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json speech-recognition@1.0.0 No README data, however, the node_modules directory still does not exist....maybe those fields MUST have something in them?

Comment: npm intstall is to install the packages from the list of "dependencies" from package.json file

Comment: to install to package initially I think you should prefer the specific command related to that package

Comment: e.g. If you want to install Express. then use the following command

Comment: npm install express --save

Comment: it will save install the express package and update your package.json file as well.

Comment: Ah, OK! Let me try that.

Comment: I have updated the answer as well. Please have a look.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I needed to do-- just having network connectivity problems now. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be self descriptive:

> npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a
>   package.json in

This means that `npm install` is not able to find the `package.json` file in the folder

You can run [**npm init**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) on the folder. This will ask a series of project set up questions and at the end will create a package.json file.

Then you can run `npm install -save-dev` on the folder to install the dependencies

Comment: npm intsall => please correct. (because its like npm integer sall =)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `npm install --save`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401934/couldnt-read-dependencies-error-with-npm

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't make this mistake but I had "dependencies" spelled wrong in the root package.json file. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and is a speculative guess, best limited to the comments section, only in the case where this question was NOT answered two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a package-lock.json file in the directory you are trying to run npm install... delete the package-lock.json file and run npm install again, this will generate all files and folders needed.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @AnthonyAstige - I had the same issue that no `node_modules` folder was being created...at least that's what I thought. I had clicked/dragged the folder I was working with into VSCode prior to running `npm install express --save`. @brk got me looking in other dir/folders and I found the path to the `node_modules` folder was in my home dir and not the folder I had dragged into VSCode.

Moral of the story...make sure you are in the correct dir, aka your project's root directory before running the install. I know, rookie mistake but apparently this is a widely discussed topic.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

> Try these possible solutions.

• Delete the node_modules folder and also delete the package-lock.json file(if already present).

• Clear the cache using npm cache clean --verify.

• And then run npm install again.

**2.**

> if package.json is missing

• Run npm init. It will create the package.json file on the fly for you.

• After this proceed as written in 1st Solution.

**3.**

> This bug may be caused by many different things. Maybe your global packages are corrupted in some way.

• Install Node Version Manager (or NVM for Windows) and install Node version 10.16.1. It is a much stable version for development. This should also change your NPM version so that may also help.

• Delete the package-lock.json file(if already present).

• Force clear cache npm cache clean --force

• You can also try clearing your %temp% and %roaming% AppData/npm-cache

• Run npm install --force.

• If this error still occurs, consider using another shell.

Answer (score -1):

You might already be having working application with package.json just paste it in new project and then enter the command npm install